# Using python multiprocessing for sklearn NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, pool

I am using dev version of Python sklearn package with NN implementation. 
My task is to train 4 NN with different input data and the average the predictions

```
X_median = preprocessing.scale(data_median)
X_min = preprocessing.scale(data_min)
X_max = preprocessing.scale(data_max)
X_mean = preprocessing.scale(data_mean)
```

I creat a Neural Networks like this

```
NN1 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (50), activation = 'logistic', algorithm='adam', alpha= 0 , max_iter = 40, batch_size = 10, learning_rate = 'adaptive', shuffle = True, random_state=1)
NN2 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (50), activation = 'logistic', algorithm='adam', alpha= 0 , max_iter = 40, batch_size = 10, learning_rate = 'adaptive', shuffle = True, random_state=1)
NN3 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (50), activation = 'logistic', algorithm='adam', alpha= 0 , max_iter = 40, batch_size = 10, learning_rate = 'adaptive', shuffle = True, random_state=1)
NN4 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (50), activation = 'logistic', algorithm='adam', alpha= 0 , max_iter = 40, batch_size = 10, learning_rate = 'adaptive', shuffle = True, random_state=1)
```

(standard sklearn function)

and I want to train them on described above datasets.
Without using pool my code will look like this:

```
NN1.fit(X_mean,train_y)
NN2.fit(X_median,train_y)
NN3.fit(X_min,train_y)
NN4.fit(X_max,train_y)
```

Of course since all 4 training are independent I want to run them in parallel, and I assume I should use pool for this. However, I do not understand completely how the computation is performed. I would assume to write something like this:

```
pool = Pool()
pool.apply_async(NN1.fit, args = (X_mean, train_y))
```

However, this does not produce any results, I can even type like this(passing only one argument) and the program will finish without any errors!
`pool.apply_async(NN1.fit, args = (X_mean,))`.

What will be the correct way to perform such computations?
Can someone advise good resource to understand the usage of Python multiprocessing?

Comment: For `apply_async` you need to provide a callback to be executed when the computation is done. I think you want `apply()`, which waits for the computation before returning.

Comment: Indeed, seems code like this do the job:
    `def Myfunc(MyNN,X,train_y):
 MyNN.fit(X,train_y)
 return MyNN`
and then
    `NN_mean = pool.apply(Myfunc, (NN_mean,X_mean, train_y))`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I made it work)

I based my solution on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments). So, firstly create two help functions:

1)

```
def Myfunc(MyNN,X,train_y):
MyBrain.fit(X,train_y)
return MyNN
```

This one is just to make desirable function global to feed pool methods

2)

```
def test_star(a_b):
return Myfunc(*a_b)
```

This is key part of it- help function to take 1 argument and split it to desirable number of args Myfunc needed.

Then just create

```
mylist = [(NN_mean,X_mean, train_y), (NN_median,X_median, train_y)]
```

and execute

```
NN_mean, NN_median = pool.map(test_star, my list).
```

From my point of view this solution is super ugly, but it works. I hope someone can create more elegant one and post it :).

Comment: Yeah, `pool` objects can only handle data in a certain way.  You can gain more flexibility with the `pathos` module, but I usually just go with a wrapper rather than using another external module.